# Out of Memory Exception only in window 8

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows

Am getting strange issue in window 8. My application is working fine on other OS (Win 7 and XP). I checked in task manager and compared my application memory both in Win7 and Win8. i found out that in window 8 my application Handlers get above 7000 and i get "out of memory exception" while in window 7 handlers never exceed 500. Why is this ? and how can i fix this issue in window 8? kindly help

Please Note this I have checked and make sure dispose is being called. As I mentioned its working fine in window 7, When I close forms, memory is getting clear. Problems come in window8. Am using same code on window 8 but memory is not getting clear and handles keep on increasing until following exception occurs

```
Error Message: 
Out of memory.
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)
   at Infragistics.Win.Misc.SplitterButtonUIElement.GetDefaultButtonImage()
   at Infragistics.Win.Misc.SplitterButtonUIElement.DrawImage(UIElementDrawParams& drawParams)
   at Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawElement(UIElementDrawParams& defaultDrawParams)
   at Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawChildElements(UIElementDrawParams& drawParams)
   at Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawElement(UIElementDrawParams& defaultDrawParams)
   at Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawChildElements(UIElementDrawParams& drawParams)
   at Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawElement(UIElementDrawParams& defaultDrawParams)
   at Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawHelper(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode, Boolean clipText, Boolean forceDrawAsFocused, Boolean preventAlphaBlendGraphics)
   at Infragistics.Win.UIElement.Draw(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode, Boolean forceDrawAsFocused, Boolean preventAlphaBlendGraphics)
   at Infragistics.Win.ControlUIElementBase.Draw(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode, Size elementSize, Boolean preventAlphaBlendGraphics)
   at Infragistics.Win.ControlUIElementBase.Draw(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode, Size elementSize)
   at Infragistics.Win.ControlUIElementBase.Draw(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode)
   at Infragistics.Win.UltraControlBase.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Well are you loading lots of images and never disposing of them? By "handlers" do you mean "handles"? Please tell us more about your application, and what you've tried to do to isolate the issue. Ideally, show a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Application using alot of image icons(Infragistic Toolbar) but I am disposing forms properly. and yes I mean handles. As I said same code working perfectly on Window 7. on form closing memory is getting cleared on form disposing but in window 8 handles getting increased and memory never cleared out.

Comment: This may happen if the image format is invalid

Comment: And have you managed to reproduce this in a short but complete program?

Comment: Yes. If i keep on opening and closing forms for couple of time exception occurs

Comment: You said the form is getting disposed, but you never said if the images are getting disposed. Please include the code showing how you create/replace/remove images.